# Cannot set data to Java Model

Tags: java, android, arrays, object, model

I have a model below which i use to add my data and get it's properties when a user selects an option. Unfortunately i am unable to get the logic right. Kindly help with the best way to set data to a model using an array.
**Unfortunately i get the error Data cannot be applied to Data[]**

Model

```
public class Data
{

private String isVerified;

private String providerType;

private String modifiedAt;

private String modifiedBy;

private String provider;

private String id;

private String accountNumber;

private String accountName;

private String createdBy;

private String isDefault;

private String createdAt;

private String userId;

private String providerId;

public String getIsVerified ()
{
    return isVerified;
}

public void setIsVerified (String isVerified)
{
    this.isVerified = isVerified;
}

public String getProviderType ()
{
    return providerType;
}

public void setProviderType (String providerType)
{
    this.providerType = providerType;
}

public String getModifiedAt ()
{
    return modifiedAt;
}

public void setModifiedAt (String modifiedAt)
{
    this.modifiedAt = modifiedAt;
}

public String getModifiedBy ()
{
    return modifiedBy;
}

public void setModifiedBy (String modifiedBy)
{
    this.modifiedBy = modifiedBy;
}

public String getProvider ()
{
    return provider;
}

public void setProvider (String provider)
{
    this.provider = provider;
}

public String getId ()
{
    return id;
}

public void setId (String id)
{
    this.id = id;
}

public String getAccountNumber ()
{
    return accountNumber;
}

public void setAccountNumber (String accountNumber)
{
    this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
}

public String getAccountName ()
{
    return accountName;
}

public void setAccountName (String accountName)
{
    this.accountName = accountName;
}

public String getCreatedBy ()
{
    return createdBy;
}

public void setCreatedBy (String createdBy)
{
    this.createdBy = createdBy;
}

public String getIsDefault ()
{
    return isDefault;
}

public void setIsDefault (String isDefault)
{
    this.isDefault = isDefault;
}

public String getCreatedAt ()
{
    return createdAt;
}

public void setCreatedAt (String createdAt)
{
    this.createdAt = createdAt;
}

public String getUserId ()
{
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId (String userId)
{
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getProviderId ()
{
    return providerId;
}

public void setProviderId (String providerId)
{
    this.providerId = providerId;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "ClassPojo [isVerified = "+isVerified+", providerType = "+providerType+", modifiedAt = "+modifiedAt+", modifiedBy = "+modifiedBy+", provider = "+provider+", id = "+id+", accountNumber = "+accountNumber+", accountName = "+accountName+", createdBy = "+createdBy+", isDefault = "+isDefault+", createdAt = "+createdAt+", userId = "+userId+", providerId = "+providerId+"]";
}
}
```

Below is my method to add data to the model

```
private void addToWallets(Data walletData) {
    Data wallet = new Data();
    wallet.setId(walletData.getId());
    wallet.setAccountNumber(walletData.getAccountNumber());
    wallets.add(wallet);
}
```

I add the response from the server to my method that i created to add data to the model:

```
if (response.isSuccess()){
                loading.dismiss();

                Data[] wallets = response.body().getData();

                addToWallets(wallets);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array of `Data` can't be converted to a single `Data` object.
I suppose that this is what you want:

```
Data[] wallets = response.body().getData();
for (Data wallet : wallets) {
    addToWallets(wallet);
}
```